# sql query using redbeans php

Tags: php, redbean

Hi I am just beginning to use redbeans ORM. I followed the docs and tried doing a query like this

```
$thebean=R::find("users","id>2");
```

and then I loop through like:-

```
foreach($thebean as $bean){
echo $bean->username;
}
```

However I find that if the even if the users table contains more than 100 data, the above query only fetches the last data . for eg: if I have users 1 to 100. I only get the user with id=100. Can somebody please tell me what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know redbeans but try: echo $bean->username;

Comment: Try `var_dump($thebean);` and see if it is an array with all your records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that it was a problem with the id field. Solved it using tableformatter option.

Comment: Can you tell me more details please? Thanks!!

Comment: Please explain, I am having the exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that your syntax is not correct? I have no experience with Redbean, but you might want to do something like this:

```
$users = R::find('users', 'id > ?', array('2'));
var_dump($users);
```

Either way, what is your result when you do the following? Does it return all your users or just one?

```
$users = R::find('users');
var_dump($users);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "findAll" on the query. So for example:

```
$thebean = R::findAll('users', 'id > 2' array('id' => 2));
```

then you can do your standard foreach:

```
foreach ($thebean as $key => $bean) {

 echo $bean->username;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be a problem on the type of field? Are you tried with: `$thebean=R::find("users","id>'2'");` ?