# RedBeanPHP fetchAll only returning one row

Tags: php, pdo, redbean

I am making a call to the database to fetch some data. I have tried the request in SQL, and it works fine. I have coded the query using PDO, and it works fine. But using RedBeanPHP with the same query only returns one result.

```
$app->get('/shoutbox/new/:msgid', function ($msgid) use ($app) {
    $messages = R::findAll('shoutbox_message', ' WHERE message_id > ? LIMIT 10', array($msgid));
    $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var_dump($messages);
    echo json_encode(R::exportAll($messages));
});
```

I have used `var_dump($messages)` to verify there's only one message being returned.

I found a similar problem here, but the OP solved it without explaining how: [sql query using redbeans php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103400/sql-query-using-redbeans-php)

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `R::findAll` which is used for when you do not want to add any conditions.  However, you have a WHERE condition in your query.  You want to use the `R::find` method instead.

I'm not sure what value is being passed is in your $msgid parameter or what the resulting $messages should contain, but the query would look like this.

`$messages = R::find('shoutbox_message', ' message_id = ? LIMIT 10', array($msgid) );`